# Term for Multiple Similar/Redundant Adjectives

Tags: adjectives, terminology, literary-techniques, literary-device, rhetorical-devices

I've been searching fervently for a potentially fictitious term that I thought I came across a while ago for structures like:

> The weather that day was so **bleak and dreary**, all I wanted to do was stay indoors by the blazing fire, sipping a warm cup of hot cocoa.

Writers often describe things with multiple (frequently two) adjectives that don't really give any more information than just one adjective would.  I thought I encountered a word to describe this idea, but I'm not really sure.

I'm not looking for terms like pleonasm, redundancy, verbosity, etc., but something specific to this structure I am describing (could of course apply to adverbs instead of adjectives as well).

Comment: *don't really give any more information* is necessarily wrong. Every word has its own connotations, including words that have the same denotations.

Comment: Are you looking for the term **tautology**? My Big Fat Greek Wedding is an example of tautology used for comic effect. Otherwise, it's a no-no in English.

Comment: @Drew 1) I disagree, 2) "don't really give any more information" is an informal way of saying "give very little additional information."

Comment: Tell me what more information you get from "My homework was hard and difficult" over "My homework was difficult."

Comment: duplicative? . . .

Comment: Perhaps I'm going slightly mad and the term I'm looking for was only ever a figment of my imagination.